# Ruby on Rails Associate pairs of one model to a second model

Tags: activerecord, associations

I'm building a rails app where I have models `users`, `images`, and `image_pairs`. I want each `image_pair` to have 2 `images`, named `:before_image` and `:after_image`.

So:

- `users` have many `images` (many to one)
- `users` have many `image_pairs` (many to one)
- `images` may have only one `image_pair`
- `image_pairs` always have 2 `images`

I have everything working, **except** I can't call `@image.image_pair`. I get:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column image_pairs.image_id does not exist`

How can I set this up so I can get an `image_pair` from its `image`?

**schema.rb** (some irrelevant fields removed)

```
create_table "image_pairs", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "before_image_id"
  t.integer  "after_image_id"
end

add_index "image_pairs", ["before_image_id"], name: "index_image_pairs_on_before_image_id", using: :btree
add_index "image_pairs", ["after_image_id"], name: "index_image_pairs_on_after_image_id", using: :btree
add_index "image_pairs", ["user_id"], name: "index_image_pairs_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "images", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "image_pair_id"
end

add_index "images", ["image_pair_id"], name: "index_images_on_image_pair_id", using: :btree
add_index "images", ["user_id"], name: "index_images_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :image_pairs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :image_pair
end
```

**image_pair.rb**

```
class ImagePair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :before_image, :class_name => "image"
  belongs_to :after_image, :class_name => "image"
end
```

Comment: I would at least change the last two `belongs_to` to `has_one`.  So `has_one :before_image...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might add a field to image_pairs called image_id that points to the original image id. Or rename the before_image to image_id and add an alias or a method if you want to call it by the name before_image.

```
def before_image
  self.image_id
end
```